# KineticJs canvas objects disappearing when running on HD screen

Tags: android, html, cordova, canvas, kineticjs

I have developed a web app, which is simply an html5 card game.
Then I have converted it to android app using `phonegap`. The app runs correctly on my older mobile phone which has `devicePixelRatio = 1`.

Then when I tried to run the app on newer mobile phone, with `devicePixelRatio = 4`, and screen resolution 1440 x 2560 (I do not know if the problem's source is this), I see the canvas with initial objects just a second correctly and then they are disappearing, and then on canvas never some thing is drawn, although the game seems start and run as usual.

Another note is, on the same phone, in android browser the app also works correctly. The problem occurs when runs as android app.

The `meta tag` that I use for `viewport` is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Android version: 5.1.1

I have passed 2 days to just discover the reason of the problem but could not get. Does somebody have any idea about the issue?

If the question lacks information please tell me. After 2 days getting nothing, I may even not be able to ask it rightly.

Comment: Have you read this article? Maybe it helps: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/?redirect_from_locale=de

Comment: Actually I did have read, but it did not me occur taking any action about my problem. KineticJs already involves in that. Then I have tried explicitly setting Kinetic.pixelRatio=4, or =1, and did not get a difference. I'll look again to the article anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Although in the question I have directed you to the device screen resolution, that I see the canvas objects just one second correctly drawn makes me to think that the problem may occur because of another thing. May some thing cause the canvas to be cleared and then paralyzing it? But just occurs when running as android app on HD screen?

Comment: Is the actual size of the canvas box changing? Have you tried to make a border around it for inspection?

Comment: @Joerg when I looked with weinre, kinetic gave me the same size for stage. And now I tried to draw border, neither painted it. The only thing it shows is the background.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with canvas and I have no experience with highresolution devices & canvas. What I think what happens is, that there is a mismatch between the stored data in the device and the shown data. I believe that you see nothing, because the data are out of space. So I would try to give the canvas a fixed dimension and make some experiments with simple drawings. And the next point is, I would check the css, maybe there is an error. And I would check it on other devices, maybe you try genimotion, it is great.

Comment: Thank you for your intent and genymotion, I anyway would need that.